# repeating check and action in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code in Swift:

```
    var changed = false

    if property1 != obj.property1 {
        property1 = obj.property1
        changed = true
    }

    if property2 != obj.property2 {
        property2 = obj.property2
        changed = true
    }

    ... until property n 

    return changed
```

is there a way to make this more concise saying that I know all the properties that I want to check, let's say I have an array = ['property1', 'property2', .. 'propertyN']. I am new to swift, I know that in C# I would use reflection.

Thanks.

Comment: From where do you get `obj.property1`? It's an array?

Comment: obj is an object of the same type as self

Answer (score 0):

If `obj` is inheriting from `NSObject` you could do something like the following:

`var value = obj.valueForKey('property1');`

Setting the value could be done via:

`obj.setValueForKey('property1', valueObject);`

**EDIT**
Under the assumption you want to use some nasty code, you could use something like this:

```
var obj = NSObject();
var selfObj = NSObject();

let propertyNames = ["property1", "property2"];
var changed = false

for property in propertyNames {
    if obj.valueForKey(property) != nil {

        let selfValue = selfObj.valueForKey(property) as! NSObject
        let objValue = obj.valueForKey(property) as! NSObject

        if selfValue != objValue {
            selfObj.setValue(objValue, forKey: property)
            changed = true
        }
    }
}
```

Needs some more `nil` checks, but you could do that yourself.

Comment: It doesnt inherit anything

Comment: Is a possibility to make it inherit from NSObject?

Comment: No, I'd rather avoid inheritance from NSObject. I was hoping that there would be a cleaner way